# at the end .aspx and .aspx.cs both of file code will be converted in single page class in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

my question was that suppose I have a .aspx page and the .aspx page has all the HTML tags and server controls as well. and also javascript and CSS will be having on that ok so I want to know when I send  the request for the .aspx page then all the code that is available on the .aspx.cs file will be merged into the .aspx file and the .aspx page will be created as a page class file as a single dll or not here is my file

```
simple.aspx
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="simple.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample.simple" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br/>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>





simple.aspx.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System. Linq;
using System. Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System. Web. UI.WebControls;

namespace sample
{
    public partial class simple: System.Web. UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Hi Sudarshan";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code file is not and NEVER merged into some file.

A class object with the code for the page is created - FROM code behind.

Then .net will load the aspx page into that class.

And then you using that class to make changes to the page.

In fact, you can see the page class code generated. Just click on show all files.

[image]

Now, your example page + code behind -- you have this:

[image]

"desinger.cs" is in fact the page class generated here.

And you can even open it up. In fact, in some RARE cases, some actually attempt to modify that designer file. But, it tends to be a bad idea, since any change to your aspx page, or code behind will cause that "designer" class code file to be re-generated, and thus any changes in that code will be lost.

You see this code (and more)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CSharpWebApp.Test5
{


    public partial class WebForm1
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// form1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

        /// <summary>
        /// label1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label label1;
```

So, just like you might have some json data, or xml data?

You can read in that xml or json data, and have the data be pushed into a class. You then use the class to see/use the values from that xml.

So the term "merge" is a VERY poor term to use here. The page class loads the aspx page, and converts (deserlizes) the markup into the page class. At that point, you have a class object with properties and methods.

I mean, the above page is called WebForm1.

I can say add another page, and do this (WebForm2).

Say a button click.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebForm1 MyPageCass = new WebForm1();

        
    }
```

In above, I just create a instance of WebForm1() as a class object!!!!

But, I can't do a whole lot, since the label and button methods are private to that class, and not exposed as public.

So, you can actually see/view/look at the class generated by .net - you find it in the "desinger" file (you do have to click on show all files).

As for a single .dll file? Well, like any old c# project - even a console applcation? Often the .dlls can be merged into a single .dll that contains all of the class objects. (but, really not much of a concern of yours).

As a general rule? You don't have to care about these bits and parts, since even as a experianced developer?

All you really want and need to know is the page life cycle, and how to write your code against that code. Any more information beyond a grasp of the page life cycle is much you wasting your time.

Now that I shared the above information?

I would not mind one bit if you came back and said

So what! - why does that matter?

Answer: it probably really does not matter one bit, except one having a too much time on their hands poindering about things that really don't matter, but MORE imporant will not help you develop code and a applcation, and that should be your end goal.

So, grasping the architecture and how this works?  yes, that always a good thing, and a grasp of say how a OS works etc.? Sure, it can help you grasp how some of the bits and parts work, and thus result in you making better design decisions. But, that kind of skill set only will be of value after you have a good number of years doing solid development work.

However, if you looking to get some work done, build a working asp.net applcation? Then this information not going to amount to anything more then a hill of beans you find on the side of the road.

And wasting too much time on this issue WILL MOST certainly make you a worse developer, since you wasting boatloads of time on issues that will not improve your abilities and coding skills to get your work done, and build a working applcation.

.net automatic abstracts these issues for you. You no more need to know the above information then say how NewtonSoft json can and does serialize and de-serialize objects for you. You need to know about the concept of serialization - very important to grasp the concept. But beyond that, you don't really give one hoot about how newtonsoft's json serialization actually gets the job done and works, unless you planning to build your own custom json library serialization , or in this case build your own custom web development system and NOT use asp.net anymore.

Spend your time grasping how to create a c# class object. And once you do that, then the concept of how asp.net + c# code behind and the fact that a asp.net page becomes a class object ALSO will become clear in your mind.

There is no use asking about how to operate on a human brain on the 8th floor of the hospital with a advanced surgical team when you not even figured out how to put a band-aid on a scraped knee, or grapsed the simple concept of a creating a class in c#.

That aspx page becomes a c# class - you really only need to know that. (how to use a class, and once you figure out that, then you find that your question is very much a waste of time, and will not matter to you anyway).

But in summary?
A c# class is generated - the designer cs file. The aspx page is loaded into that class. Your code behind thus operates against that class object. The class object after your code runs against that class is then rendered into html and sent to the client browser.

So the question of a single.dll being created? Depends on how the project is being compiled - in some cases the.dll's are merged into one dll, or each class can result in a single dll. That.dll only contains the class code - not the aspx markup. The resulting class created is able to load and consume the aspx page.
So at deployment time, the c# or VB.net source code doesn't have to exist on the web server, but the aspx page with have to reside on the web server.

In fact if you deploy as a web site, then IIS will compile on the fly the c# code into the class (after having generated the designer file.).

If you choose a web site application, then this compile of code occurs in visual studio and the code is compiled before you deploy to the server. Thus c#)vb source code is not required on the web server, but in both cases the source aspx page is required.

more FYI:

What do you get if your markup page is this:

```
        <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br/>
        <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="button1_Click" />

        <div id="mycooldiv">

        </div>
```

Well, you can open up the desinger cs generated class. You not find the "div" in that class. But, ANY time you tag anything with runat=server?

then that DOES become part of the class.

So, we then can do this:

```
        <div id="mycooldiv" runat="server">

        </div>
```

now, mycooldiv becomes part of that .net class. And in code behind, I can now do this:

```
    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Hi Sudarshan";

        mycooldiv.InnerText = "this is some text in the div";

    }
```

And if we open up the desinger cs file, we will indded see a new property/method of the class has been added.

eg:

/// 
/// mycooldiv control.
/// 
/// 
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// 
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl mycooldiv;

So, any asp.net control, or in fact even html controls? If you want them to become part of that generated class, then you have to include a runat="server". The result is then you can with great ease use such controls in code behind.

If you don't add the runat=server, then you don't get all of the nice properties and methods of that control

```
        label1.Text = "Hi Sudarshan";
        mycooldiv.InnerHtml = @"<font bold size='8' color='red'>This is bold text</font>";
```

And we now get this:

[image]

So, if you want the markup to become part of the page class (so you can easy with code manipulate that control on the page) then include the runat=server. When you do that, then the generated page class will include and wire up a methods and properties of that given control into the page class object.

Comment: thanks a lot, today I was able to understand all things because of you one more thing I want to know is whether HTML tags will also be part of that designer class file or not.

Comment: Good question. And the answer is those tags will not UNLESS you add the runat=server. As above shows, I wanted easy use of a div, so I add a id, and also the runat=server. And thus now I can use the control in code behind. The markup is not pulled into the designer class, but a valid control with properties and methods is created. Again those properties and methods operate against the loaded "DOM".